# Conditions for a function to be a product of 2 or more functions

Tags: functions, products

Given an arbitrary function of two variables, say $f(x_1,x_2)$, what are the conditions that $f$ has to satisfy such that $f(x_1,x_2)=g_1(x_1)g_2(x_2)$? And in general, $f(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)=g_1(x_1)g_2(x_2)...g_n(x_n)$ i.e. $f$ is completely multiplicatively separable.

Will $g_i$ be of any specific nature?

Comment: If there are no zeros then the first property holds iff $f(x,y)=cf(x,1)f(1,y)$ for some constant $c$. Similar characterization holds for any $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you figure this? Obviously if that holds then $f$ is separable, that condition is basically a re-phrasing of the condition "$f$ is separable". However, the converse is not as self evident - would it not be necessary to say $f(x,y)=xf(x,m)f(n,y)$ for some constants $c,m,n$? It is still clearly separable in that context, because the condition statement *is* a separation of variables.

Comment: If my condition holds then it is already the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$. No further condition is needed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes but you implied the statements were biconditional; if $f$ is a product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$, it isn't clear that it necessarily satisfies your condition. Obviously if the 1's were replaced by arbitrary constants it would be trivially true, but at that point we're saying "a function is separable if it is separable." The new condition is basically a restatement of the original one.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We know $f(x,1)$ will not be identically zero because you already assumed that there are no zeroes. However, I did some working out and while my formulation would still be correct, yours is as well so mine is needlessly generalized.

Comment: (This was cut off from the last comment.) It wasn't evident to me at first, but here's the reasoning for mine:

$f(x,y)=Cg_1(x)g_2(y)=(C'g_1(n)g_2(m))g_1(x)g_2(y)=C''f(x,m)f(n,y)$. 

Thus $f(x,y)=Cg_1(x)g_2(y) \implies f(x,y)=cf(x,m)f(n,y)$. However, I had previously thought that m,n would need to be arbitrary to represent ALL functions; this is not the case, so taking $(m,n)=(1,1)$ still gives a valid argument (and makes a practical test easier).

Answer (score 0):

A possible test is $$\frac{f(x,a)}{f(x,b)}=\frac{g_2(a)}{g_2(b)}=\text{Cst}.$$

There are no restrictions on the $g_i$, as the product is always defined.

Comment: Should that not be $g_2(a)$ and $g_2(b)$? Also, from a practical stance, this isn't a useful test, since we probably don't know any $g_i$; can we find a more practical condition or show one doesn't exist?

Comment: @Vedvart1: fixed. No, you needn't know $g_2$. And the method generalizes to $n$.

Comment: Naturally, you just need to be able to show that the ratio is constant - didn't notice that. Maybe edit in the generalization for $n$? It isn't super clear, to me at least, how the nicest way to express it would be.